# Is angular 2 only for spa applications?

Tags: web, angular

Could not find much information on whether we can use angular 2 for non SPA applications. For example any major health insurance website out there. Most of the example I am reading online are talking in terms of SPAs. One reason being I am just starting to learn Angular 2 and could not yet draw conclusions on Angular 2's flexibility. Can you enlighten please?

Comment: You can build non-SPA sites as well. Basically any non-SPA site is just a collection of SPA sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Angular 2 for building any type of application, not only single page application.

Angular 2's philosophy embraces the composite design pattern, so you could design every section of your site with components.

And of course you can link all these components together in a SPA if that's what you want.